# How to block, catch and handle several signals and keystroke event from a non blocking CLI?

Tags: c++, c, unix, signals

- **Language**: C++ and C
- **OS**: UNIX-like (POSIX)
- **Context**: A real-time process for sonification/visualization of abstract data streams, from file or piped from another program, which is being conrolled by means of a simple non-blocking command-line interface.
- **Description**: `sig_handler()` and `sig_timed_kbhit()` are the functions which take care of dispatching the real-time execution termination gently, caused by user hitting `<enter>` or ^C, while processing data either from file or `STDIN` redirection/pipe.
- **Arguments**: `fd` is either `STDIN_FILENO` or the `int` value returned by `open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR)` in the calling function. The `struct timeval tv` is the *timeout period* passed by the *calling function*.
- **Problem**: It would also have to block, catch and handle `SIGTSTP` and `SIGCONT`, possibly `SIGQUIT` as well. I haven't come across examples how this can be done. Does one have to call for `sigfillset()`, need multiple (nested?) signal handlers, `struct sigaction`s, `sigset_t`s?
- **Research** done so far:
  I have a *fully working solution* for handling `<enter>` and `SIGINT`

Generic signal handler for `SIGINT`:

```
void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGINT){
        std::cout<<"\nreceived SIGINT"<<std::endl;
        //code for handling SIGINT
        ;
}
```

Working code for handling `<enter>` and `^C`:

```
bool sig_timed_kbhit(int fd, struct timeval tv)
{
    // Installing signal handler for SIGINT
    struct sigaction s;
    s.sa_handler = sig_handler;
    sigemptyset(&s.sa_mask);
    s.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &s, NULL);

    // Blocking SIGINT
    sigset_t sigset, prev_set;
    sigemptyset(&sigset);
    sigaddset(&sigset, SIGINT);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, &prev_set);

    struct timespec ts;
    TIMEVAL_TO_TIMESPEC(&tv, &ts);
    fd_set read_fd;
    FD_ZERO(&read_fd);
    FD_SET(fd, &read_fd);

    if (pselect(fd+1, &read_fd, NULL, NULL, &ts, &prev_set) < 0)
        std::cerr<<"select"<<std::endl;

    bool   b = (FD_ISSET(fd, &read_fd)) ;
    return b;
}
```

Any suggestions which would cast some light on how to elegantly solve such a task would be kindly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks a bit like homework.

Comment: The shown signal handler is undefined behavior, and will result in random crashes, since C++ library's streams are not reentrant. That's one issue. Now, if the domain of the question is Linux, then the Linux kernel's signal file descriptors can be used to implement a unified file descriptor-based event dispatching loop.

Comment: Would solutions that do not use signals be enough?  In what way is this a [c] question?  How much control do you have over the "main processing" part of the code?

Comment: Solutions that don't use signals are fairly simple and I know them, but wouldn't be enough, thanks for asking, @Yakk. This is a C question in sense that I hope the same paradigm could function in both languages, and **it does**, as far as SIGINT is the only signal being concerned (i.e. caught and handled).

Comment: A shamefully simple solution I've come across by experimenting consists of: also registering `sigaction(SIGTSTP, &s, NULL);` `sigaction(SIGQUIT, &s, NULL);` and adding these signal numbers to the `sigset` one-by-one using `sigaddset()` in the function `sig_timed_kbhit()`, providing the `sig_handler()` also has valid code to take care of these signals caught.

Comment: @ElizabethMyers, would you please be so kind to give a hint: (1) what makes you think this is "a bit like" homework? (2) what makes you think this question deserves no more than posting such a laconically disqualifying comment? Thanks.